# Performing viewshed in QGIS with GPS satellites?

Tags: qgis, viewshed

I want to do viewshed analysis in QGIS.

My observer points are gps satellites the actual elevations are scaled down from 35000 kms to 1500m but the positions are accurate i,e elevation and azimuth.

This I am able to do in ArcGIS Desktop with not much difficulty by defining input raster, observation points(gps satellites), surfface offset (offsetB), observer elevation i,e 1500m and offsetA (1).

How do I define the similar parameters in QGIS and what shall be the search radius (default shown as 5000)?

No output is coming in QGIS.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you want to do. By input raster, do you mean a DEM? And you want the viewshed to take into account the terrain? Also, is it supposed to be what the viewshed of a GPS satellite at 1500m would be like?

Comment: Input raster is a DEM, yes the viewshed should take into account the terrain. I am considering the observer points as GPS satellites and the results of viewshed shall be displayed on the DEM showing visible and non-visible areas.